# how to crash the main process if there is unhandled exception inside background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, com, background-thread

I have a publisher, dispatcher, subscriber.

publisher publish event through dispatcher to subscriber.

subscriber is a com object embedded in S.exe can be callback from dispatcher.exe when specific event coming from publisher.exe.

**I expect any exception inside the subscriber to terminate the S.exe.**

I did my investigation:

1. task, with 
   configuration can terminate the main process. related article, 
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=netframework-4.7.2
2. new a thread in my code, without any specific configuration can
       also, any unhandled exception inside the thread can crash the main
       process. related article,
       https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/exceptions-in-managed-threads

two attributes of one thread: {isbackground, isThreadPoolThread}.

1. task is {true, true}
2. artificial thread is {true, false},
3. subscriber callback thread is {true, false}.

is there any other configuration, like , can set to control whether or not to crash the main process?

Comment: You must do this programmatically so you can take care of the *other* essential detail.  Super-duper important that you leave some kind of breadcrumb so the user can discover why the program terminated.  You don't have a lot of options since you cannot control the user interface, System.Diagnostics.EventLog is all you really have.  Then Environment.FailFast().

Answer (score 0):

You can handle `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event in which you can get the current process by using `Process.GetCurrentProcess()` and kill that process so your `exe` will terminate.

Put this line `Main()` in `Program.cs`:

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException`

Then implement `CurrentDomain_UnhandledException` as below.

```
private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    currentProcess.Kill();
}
```

This is just concept as per your problem statement. You can change it as per your need.

Comment: Hi, Ramoliya, actually, this is my main function,[STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, args) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show(args.ExceptionObject.ToString());
            };

            TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (sender, args) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show(args.ToString());
            };
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1);
        }

Comment: So you are already handling the `UnhandledException ` Just put process kill lines in that like this.

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, args) =>
    {
     MessageBox.Show(args.ExceptionObject.ToString());
        var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        currentProcess.Kill();
    };

Comment: the problem is in my attached code above, I didn't got the message box. so, can I guess, it also can not kill my process using you proposed way?

Answer (score 0):

Any exception inside a COM was wrapped as a HRESULT return to it's client by RCW.
So, no way to crash the main process when the exception was thrown inside a COM thread.

The answer may be related with: 
**COM methods report errors by returning HRESULTs; .NET methods report them by throwing exceptions. The runtime handles the transition between the two. Each exception class in the .NET Framework maps to an HRESULT.**

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/how-to-map-hresults-and-exceptions

and other helpful links: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/runtime-callable-wrapper

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/com-callable-wrapper